# Find count of N-digits numbers which consist of digits give you the sum is equal to K. Return count, the smallest and the largest number

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops

I am finding for the effecient solution on that [task](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5877e7d568909e5ff90017e6/train/python)

You are given K is summ of digits are in number and N is count of digits in the number.

So you have to find count of all numbers, the smallest number and the largest number.

Also It has to be sorted number. For example:

```
145 - sorted number, because 4 > 1, and 5 > 4.
382 - not sorted number, because 3 < 8, but 8 > 2.
```

Everything must correspond to the condition of the problem.

Here is what I did:

```
def find_all(sum_dig, digs):
    min_num = 10000000000000000
    max_num = -1
    count = 0
    for i in range((10 ** digs // 10), 10 ** digs):
        summ = 0
        for j in range(len(str(i))):
            summ += int((str(i))[j])
        if summ == sum_dig and str(i) == ''.join(sorted(str(i))):
            count += 1
            if i > max_num:
                max_num = i
            if i < min_num:
                min_num = i

    if count == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return [count, min_num, max_num]
```

But that code works pretty slow, I get the error `Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)`

Could you tell is there any way to make it more effecient?

Any advices are appreciated!

Comment: Try `sum(map(int, str(i)))` as a simpler way of summing the digits of `i`.

Comment: @Samwise It works, but unfourtunately, it does not solve the problem. I guess the main problem is my first loop which iterates through pretty large numbers and makes a lot of actions with them

Comment: There is no need to find explicitly all numbers that satisfy these conditions. The smallest and the biggest number can be computed quickly without finding any other numbers. The count of all these numbers can be computed recursively: if the number of digits N is 1, you will have either 0 or 1 such number; if N is bigger, you can compute the count of N-digit numbers in terms of counts of N-1 digit numbers.

Comment: @bb1 how do you compute the largest quickly? My answer includes only an O(n, k) approach to computing the largest.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Set all digits of the number to `K//N`. Then add 1  to each of the last `K%N` digits.

Comment: @bb1 oh, right, thanks! Proven by always being able to increase the value by shifting a 1 to the left if it's available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than iterating for every number from `10^(digs-1)` until `10^digs`, which will have a broad search space, we can iterate by adding the digit in a non-decreasing manner one by one from the leftmost digit to the rightmost digit (or non-increasing manner from right to left if you prefer it).
[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-n-digit-numbers-whose-sum-of-digits-equals-to-given-sum/)

I tested the python code below on the site and it seems to solve the task.

I think the time complexity of this code can still be improved.

You can try searching about top-down dynamic programming and memoization technique if you want to optimize it.

```
def find_all(sum_dig, digs):
    global total_count, lowest_value, greatest_value
    
    total_count = 0
    lowest_value = -1
    greatest_value = -1
    
    # complete search via depth first search
    def dfs(digit_sum, digit_count, num, digit_from):
        global total_count, lowest_value, greatest_value
        
        # base case
        if digit_count == digs:
            if digit_sum == sum_dig:
                if lowest_value == -1:
                    lowest_value = num
                greatest_value = num
                total_count += 1
            return
        
        # try all possible values one by one
        for i in range(digit_from, 10):
            dfs(digit_sum + i, digit_count + 1, num * 10 + i, i)
    
    dfs(0, 0, 0, 1)
    
    answer = []
    if total_count > 0:
        answer = [total_count, lowest_value, greatest_value]
    return answer
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take with a function for each value required, which seems to pass the tests (when returning an empty list if the partition count is zero).

For the number of results, we can modify the recursion for partitions with restricted number of parts: take (1) the count of all partitions of `n-k` into `k` parts that have largest part at most `l-1` and add to them (2) the count of all partitions of `n-1` into `k-1` parts that have largest part at most `l`. (For each part in (1) add 1, for a total of `k` `1`s. For each partition in (2), add a part `1`.) `O(n, k)` search space.

```py
def f(n, k, l, memo={}):
  if k == 0 and n == 0:
    return 1

  if n <= 0 or k <= 0 or l <= 0:
    return 0

  if (n, k, l) in memo:
    return memo[(n, k, l)]

  memo[(n, k, l)] = f(n - k, k, l-1, memo) + f(n - 1, k - 1, l, memo)

  return memo[(n, k, l)]
```

For the smallest, we can use a greedy `O(n)` approach from left to right, always picking the smallest possible digit.

```py
def g(n, k):
  if k == 0:
    return 0

  next_digit = max(1, n - 9 * (k - 1))

  return next_digit * 10 ** (k - 1) + g(n - next_digit, k - 1)
```

For the largest, I couldn't think of a better approach than a recursion that limits the choice for the digit based on the current state. `O(n, k)`. bb1 [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/130292178) an `O(n)` solution for this one.

```py
from math import ceil

def h(n, k, largest):
  if n < 0:
    return 0

  if k == 1:
    return n

  best = 0
  digit = 0
  
  for i in range(
    min(largest, n - k + 1),
    min(largest, ceil(n / k)) - 1,
    -1):
    candidate = h(n - i, k - 1, i)
    if candidate > best:
      best = candidate
      digit = i

  return digit + 10 * best
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach that collects 1 digit at a time into a list until it reaches the specified total returning the value if its sum matches correctly.  Then we can make heavy use of filtering to avoid testing numbers that we know will either exceed the target sum or are not in increasing order, cutting down the potential amount of values we have to check significantly.

I tested on the website and it does pass all tests within the allotted time.

The `find_all` function merely takes the result and puts it into the format required by the challenge.

```
def find_all(sum_dig, digs):
    result = find_count(sum_dig, digs, [])
    size, sm, lg = len(result), min(result), max(result)
    return [size, sm, lg]


def find_count(sum_dig, digs, lst=[]):
    if len(lst) == digs:
        if sum(lst) == sum_dig:
            return [int(''.join([str(i) for i in lst]))]
        return []
    combos = []
    start = 1 if not len(lst) else lst[-1]
    for i in range(start, 10):
        t = 0 if not lst else sum(lst)
        if t + i <= total:
            combos += find_count(sum_dig, digs, lst + [i])
    return combos
```

Answer (score 0):

> find all numbers which give you the sum equal to s

```
m, s = map(int, input('').split(' ')) # m: length , s : sum of digits
result = []

counter = 0
def getSum(n):
    sum = 0
    while (n != 0):
        sum = sum + (n % 10)
        n = n // 10
    return sum


for i in range((10 ** (m - 1)), (10 ** m)):
    r = getSum(i)
    if r == s:
       counter += 1
       result.append(i)

print(counter, result)
```